# MYSQL JOIN | Ordenar 2° columna sin afectar la 1°

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo un JOIN entre dos tablas, la tabla **entrada_salida** y la tabla **pago**.
En el cual ordeno el JOIN por medio del **id_entrada_salida**.
El detalle aqui, es que intento ordenar la segunda tabla (pago) por medio de la columna **cobertura_pago** pero sin afectar el **id_entrada_salida**
Les muestro las tablas que tengo.

Tabla entrada_salida.

```
+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| id_entrada_salida | cliente_entrada_salida | fecha_entrada_salida | hora_entrada_salida |
+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|               104 |                     21 | 2021-06-22           | 10:20:19            |
|               103 |                     21 | 2021-06-22           | 10:10:07            |
|               102 |                     53 | 2021-06-15           | 12:30:03            |
|               101 |                     53 | 2021-06-14           | 12:13:34            |
|               100 |                     21 | 2021-06-14           | 12:13:21            |
|                99 |                     56 | 2021-06-14           | 12:11:30            |
|                98 |                     40 | 2021-06-14           | 12:11:10            |
|                97 |                     48 | 2021-06-14           | 12:11:07            |
|                96 |                     49 | 2021-06-14           | 12:10:52            |
|                95 |                     52 | 2021-06-14           | 12:10:38            |
|                94 |                     54 | 2021-06-14           | 12:10:16            |
|                93 |                     55 | 2021-06-14           | 12:09:59            |
|                92 |                     56 | 2021-06-14           | 12:08:20            |
|                91 |                     57 | 2021-06-14           | 12:08:01            |
|                90 |                     58 | 2021-06-14           | 12:07:21            |
```

Y la tabla pago.

```
+---------+---------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
| id_pago | nombre_cliente_pago | cobertura_pago | pago    | fecha_creacion_pago |
+---------+---------------------+----------------+---------+---------------------+
|      48 |                  21 | 2021-07-11     | 1000.00 | 2021-06-22          |
|      47 |                  21 | 2021-06-30     |  400.00 | 2021-06-22          |
|      43 |                  21 | 2021-06-15     |  500.00 | 2021-06-22          |
|      42 |                  56 | 2021-06-16     |  123.00 | 2021-06-18          |
|      41 |                  60 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      40 |                  59 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      39 |                  58 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      38 |                  57 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      37 |                  56 | 2021-06-15     |  300.00 | 2021-06-11          |
|      36 |                  56 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      35 |                  55 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      34 |                  54 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      33 |                  20 | 2021-04-04     |  900.50 | 2021-04-25          |
|      32 |                  30 | 2021-04-03     |  900.00 | 2021-04-24          |
|      31 |                  30 | 2021-04-02     | 1234.00 | 2021-04-24          |
|      29 |                  53 | 2021-04-08     |  300.00 | 2021-04-02          |
|      28 |                  53 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      27 |                  52 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      26 |                  51 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      25 |                  50 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      24 |                  49 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      23 |                  48 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      22 |                  47 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      21 |                  46 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      20 |                  45 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      19 |                  44 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      18 |                  42 | NULL           |    NULL | NULL                |
|      17 |                  53 | 1971-01-27     |  490.00 | NULL                |
```

Hago un **LEFT JOIN** para unir las dos tablas y que se ordene por medio del **id_entrada_salida**
Lo hago de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT
    es.id_entrada_salida AS 'id_entrada_salida',
    es.cliente_entrada_salida AS 'cliente_entrada_salida',
    es.fecha_entrada_salida AS 'f_entrada_salida',
    
    IFNULL(p.id_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_pago',
    IFNULL(p.nombre_cliente_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'id_cliente_en_el_pago',
    IFNULL(p.cobertura_pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'cobertura_pago',
    IFNULL(p.pago, 'Sin datos') AS 'pago'
    
FROM entrada_salida es
LEFT JOIN pago p
ON es.cliente_entrada_salida = p.nombre_cliente_pago
ORDER BY es.id_entrada_salida
DESC;
```

El cual me da lo siguiente:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+
| id_entrada_salida | cliente_entrada_salida | f_entrada_salida | id_pago   | id_cliente_en_el_pago | cobertura_pago |
+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+----------------+
|               104 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 43        | 21                    | 2021-06-15     |
|               104 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 47        | 21                    | 2021-06-30     |
|               104 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 48        | 21                    | 2021-07-11     |
|               103 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 43        | 21                    | 2021-06-15     |
|               103 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 47        | 21                    | 2021-06-30     |
|               103 |                     21 | 2021-06-22       | 48        | 21                    | 2021-07-11     |
|               102 |                     53 | 2021-06-15       | 17        | 53                    | 1971-01-27     |
|               102 |                     53 | 2021-06-15       | 28        | 53                    | Sin datos      |
|               102 |                     53 | 2021-06-15       | 29        | 53                    | 2021-04-08     |
|               101 |                     53 | 2021-06-14       | 17        | 53                    | 1971-01-27     |
|               101 |                     53 | 2021-06-14       | 28        | 53                    | Sin datos      |
|               101 |                     53 | 2021-06-14       | 29        | 53                    | 2021-04-08     |
|               100 |                     21 | 2021-06-14       | 43        | 21                    | 2021-06-15     |
|               100 |                     21 | 2021-06-14       | 47        | 21                    | 2021-06-30     |
|               100 |                     21 | 2021-06-14       | 48        | 21                    | 2021-07-11     |
```

El detalle esta en la columna **cobertura_pago**.
El detalle aquí que quiero conseguir, es el orden de la columna **cobertura_pago** quede de forma **DESC** sin afectar el orden de **id_entrada_salida**.
Quiero ordenar de mayor a menor, la columna **cobertura_pago** sin afectar el **id_entrada_salida**.
También si tiene como atributo **Sin datos** quede al final de las fechas.
Todo esto sin afectar el orden de **id_entrada_salida**
Quisiera un resultado como este:

```
104 21  2021-06-22  48  21  2021-07-11
104 21  2021-06-22  47  21  2021-06-30
104 21  2021-06-22  43  21  2021-06-15
103 21  2021-06-22  48  21  2021-07-11
103 21  2021-06-22  47  21  2021-06-30
103 21  2021-06-22  43  21  2021-06-15
102 53  2021-06-15  29  53  2021-04-08
102 53  2021-06-15  17  53  1971-01-27
102 53  2021-06-15  28  53  Sin datos
101 53  2021-06-14  29  53  2021-04-08
101 53  2021-06-14  17  53  1971-01-27
101 53  2021-06-14  28  53  Sin datos
```

Gracias de antemano y cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta añadiendo lo siguiente a tu ORDER BY amigo:

```
ORDER BY es.id_entrada_salida DESC, p.cobertura_pago DESC
```

Esa es la estructura para ordenar más de un campo.

Comment: Al hacer eso, me cambia el orden de id_entrada_salida

Comment: Ponle DESC a ambos campos

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Edgar esa es la solución. Gracias por tu respuesta.